# Convert string log to Json format

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm reading a log file where an application write the below code logs

```js
["TRUE",[["6/6",1],["5/5",6]]]
```

i try some replace to convert it to that is valid json format

```js
{
  "Status": "TRUE",
  "Wins": [{
    "categoryId": "6/6",
    "winOccurence": 1
  }, {
    "categoryId": "5/5",
    "winOccurence": 6
  }]
}
```

but without success .
Any idea?
Best Regards

Comment: hmm, where do you want to convert it?.. thru javascript or vb.net? better provide more details , and you can use triple backtick, for more readable format on your code

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the data in an object and for the `wins` array, you can make use of `map`. Here is a working example:

```js
var data=["TRUE",[["6/6",1],["5/5",6]]];

var obj={
 status:data[0], 
 wins:data[1].map(([categoryId, winOccurance])=>({categoryId, winOccurance}))
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the log always had the same structure you can do something like this:

```
var log = ["TRUE",[["6/6",1],["5/5",6]]]

var result = {
  "Status": log[0],
  "Wins": [{
    "categoryId": log[1][0][0],
    "winOccurence": log[1][0][1]
  }, {
    "categoryId": log[1][1][0],
    "winOccurence": log[1][1][1]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructue the array and get a new object.

```js
var data = ["TRUE", [["6/6", 1], ["5/5", 6]]],
    result = (
        ([Status, Wins]) => ({
            Status,
            Wins: Wins.map(([categoryId, winOccurence]) => ({ categoryId, winOccurence }))
        })
        )(data);

console.log(result);
```